# How can I have a Flash video not autoplay after the first visit?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

How can I have a Flash video not autoplay after the first visit?

Answer (score 1):

Set a flash cookie after the video's played, and have the player check for its existence every time it fires up. If the cookie's present, then don't start playing.

You can do the same thing with a regular cookie, and just output the appropriate `<param>` based on the cookie's presence/content.

Answer (score 1):

Use a SharedObject:
http://jaycsantos.com/flash/the-trick-to-using-sharedobject/

Comment: good way to deny autoplay on each browser of user, but if you already have sessions in php/etc use them as a part of all architecture, if not **SO** is a best way to implement such functionality.